# Cannot connect to Reporting Services 2005 Server from SSMS

Tags: reporting-services, ssms, reportingservices-2005, ssms-2005

We have SQL Server Reporting Services 2005 (SSRS) installed and running just fine. I can connect via SQL Server Management Studio 2005 using "Connect -> Reporting Services" and "Windows Authentication".

When I am connected, I can bring up the server properties and view Permissions and see myself there w/ System Administrator checked, but not System User. Which is fine because I have no problem accessing the entirety of the server.

Using the same "permissions" dialog, I use the "Add Group or User" button to add my colleagues domain account (I have tried this with just "System Administrator" and also with "System User" checked).

My colleague cannot connect. He gets the following error message when trying to connect:

> ### TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to XXXXXXXXXX.
>
> ---
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A connection to the report server failed. Most likely, you do not have
>   permission to connect to the computer. You should either try to
>   connect using a report server URL for the Server name, or if the
>   Distributed COM Users group exists on the remote computer, verify that
>   you are a member. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.RSClient)

Anyone know what else I need to do to allow him to connect to Reporting Services via SSMS?

Note: I can give him permissions to reports and he can view those reports via the SSRS website.

Comment: Firewall issues, perhaps?

Comment: According to my DBA, it would appear that in order to make this work, we would need to give my colleague SA rights. There might be another option, but we don't have time to pursue it at this time. Since we don't wish to give him SA rights at this time, we are not going in that direction either.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft link below has an article that summarizes the connection syntax, operations, and permissions required to connect to SSRS.

Basically, the user connecting has to be assigned to the System Administrator role. If this doesn't work, you will need to add the account to the 'Distributed COM Users' local group, that should let you connect via SSMS.

see here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159797.aspx and

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2793/sql-server-reporting-services-2012-permissions/

Comment: Thanks for the info. Unfortunately, according to my DBA, that did not help.